# Выделение грамматических основ в предложении

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, основа

> Мы полагаем, что во всякой истине всегда есть нечто ложное и что сходство между истиной и ложью так велико, что нет такого отличительного признака, на основании которого можно было бы судить наверняка.

Грамматические основы:

- *"Мы полагаем"*
- *"есть нечто"*
- *"так велико"*
- *"можно было бы судить наверняка"*

Правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грамматическая основа должна состоять только из подлежащего и сказуемого.В вашем последнем примере Вы включили и наречие. Это ошибка. Правильно: можно было бы судить. В остальном все верно.

Answer (score 2):

Третья грамматическая основа -"сходство велико". Четвертая гр.основа - "нет"

Answer (score 2):

Вторая грамматическая основа: есть нечто ложное. Когда в подлежащем заключено значение неопределенности (обычно выражаемое неопределенными местоименными словами), в таких случаях всё словосочетание образует один член предложения.

Другой пример:

```
Мы купили нечто интересное.
```

В данном случае *нечто интересное* — это дополнение.